# How to parameterise specs in conf.js of Protractor Framework?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am new to protractor framework,working on parameterising specs in conf.js...seeked help,googled but didn't get a solution...if any one is aware kindly help me...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to parameterize in conf.js ?

Comment: For example below is my config.js file:

exports.config = {
  specs: ['todo-spec.js','log.js']
};

If i have 10 .js files...how can i pass those .js file names as parameters in to the specs : [i want to pass the .js titles as parameters]

Comment: If it was useful, please upvote or accept my answer by clicking on right tick mark at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multiple files in protractor better use the naming conventions.

For example if there are two files :

> todo-spec.js
>
> log.js

If both files are in D:/Folder

Better name it in following way:

> todo-spec.test.js
>
> log.test.js

And for the spec file use the following way:

```
exports.config ={ specs: ['D:/Folder/*test.js']};
```

These will make sure that all your files containing test.js as a part of file name will run.
So keep a habit of writing test after every file.

I hope you are clear now. :-)

You can use `multicapabilities` , if you can:

```
exports.config = {
specs: [
// keep this blank 
 ],

multiCapabilities: [{
'browserName': 'chrome',
'specs': ['todo-spec.js']
 }, {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'specs': ['log.js']
 }, {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'specs': ['test.js']
 }],
 };
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your spontaneous reply... i need to specify .js file names based on data setup in the runtime...so if there is a way for passing .js file names as parameter in to " specs: [parameter] " in the run-time...it will be very helpful

Comment: So you might be having regression test cases, smoke test cases . M i right ? What are your categories ?

Comment: Yes..u r right...we have smoke,regression and e2e...actually we got a requirement like i need to have an excel sheet with the test case titles (in the format of .js) based on the flag(Yes/No) selection the test cases need to be executed...for ex : if 2 test case titles are selected as YES only those test cases need to executed and generate the report.

Comment: If there is way to parameterise the conf.js file i may proced with the rest...but im not able to build an dynamic conf.js

Comment: Actually what we do is, We have different folders for different test. So while running the scripts , we pick the folder as i showed you in my answer to run a suite.

Comment: Data Driven techniques through Excel/Json is achievable for test cases but I am not sure how to put it in Conf.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with tools like Grunt and Gulp but it sounds to me like you will probably need one of them to do this. If I had the same requirements as you I would setup a Gulp task that opened your excel/csv file and put the file names of the tests you want to run into a list. Then you can use that same gulp task to kick off your protractor tests by using a package like `gulp-protractor` to run the tests. You will need to work out the logic to get your list of files on your own but here is an example of how to use a gulp task to do this:

```
gulp.task("e2e", function() {
    //logic to get list of spec files here

    gulp.src([<array/list of spec files>])
    .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: "test/protractor.config.js"           
    }))
    .on('error', function(e) { throw e })
})
```